# I lost disk 1 of GTA 5 for XBox 360

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I lost my disk 1 to GTA 5 on Xbox 360. I still have disk 2 but I lost all downloadable content off the xbox's hard drive. What can I do to recover my data?

Comment: Gamefly might be your friend right now.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest going over to Rockstar Games [support page](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/requests/new), and submitting a ticket asking if you can buy a replacement disc.

I have no clue what Rockstar Games support system or policies are like, but I have heard countless stories of many gamers contacting support and getting assistance replacing missing game peripherals and game discs.

Publishers won't advertise that you can call them up and order individual game discs, but many offer this service because they understand that if you scratch a disc in a 2-3 disc game, most players would want to find a cheaper way to replace the disc than getting an entirely new copy.  Plus, buying from them puts a few more bucks in their pockets, rather than the second-hand market.

Give it a shot.  It can't hurt, and I'd be interested in getting a comment below on what they say.  I'll try to update this answer, depending on how it turns out for you.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot recover your data.

If you have a gold account, you will be able to download your save games from the cloud, however, for the install disc 1, you will need to borrow a copy from somebody and install it again and use your disc 2 to play normally.

Answer (score -1):

I think you'll have to re-download the downloadable content on the XBOX 360's Settings, under Download History.

Other than that, I don't see how else you could get it back.